# Testing the Erdos square free conjecture

Tags: number-theory, homework

Can someone please answer these two parts of my homework assignment? Adding an explanation would be appreciated!

> a. Test the Erdos square free conjecture for $n <= 30000$. You should use `SquareFreeQ`. Give the time it takes to perform this test.

For this part, I said,

```
{#, SquareFreeQ[#]} & /@ {Binomial[5, 30000]}
```

> b. Now test using your `squareFreeQ` and give the time it takes to perform this test.

For this part, my `squareFreeQ` is:

```
squareFreeQ[n_Integer] := Select[FactorInteger[n][[All, 2]], # > 1 &] == {}
```

For part b, my answer is:

```
{#, squareFreeQ[#]} & /@ {Binomial[5, 30000]}
```

But none of the answers seem to be correct.

Comment: Welcome!  If this is homework then you should add the homework tag.

Comment: `Binomial[5, 30000]` gives only the binomial for $n=30000$ instead of $n\leq 30000$.

Answer (score 4):

part (a)

```
data = Table[n, {n, 5, 3000}];
Timing[
 res = {#, SquareFreeQ[Binomial[2 #, #]]} & /@ data;
 Cases[res, {n_, True}]
 ]

(* {0.280802, {}} *)
```

part (b)

```
data = Table[n, {n, 5, 3000}];
mySquareFreeQ[n_Integer] := TrueQ[Length[Cases[FactorInteger[n], 
                                         {p_, m_} /; m > 1 :> True]] == 0];
Timing[
 res = {#, mySquareFreeQ[Binomial[2 #, #]]} & /@ data;
 Cases[res, {n_, True}]
 ]

(* {2.215214, {}} *)
```

Mathematica wins easily. I used 3000 instead of 30000 because my implementation is much slower than M and it was taking too long.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation of `mySquareFreeQ` probably comes under the heading of "not what the teacher intended" :-)

```
mySquareFreeQ = Thread[MoebiusMu@# != 0] &
```

Timings:

```
data = Binomial[2 #, #] &@Range[5, 30000];

Timing[Nor @@ SquareFreeQ /@ data]
(* {0.140625, True} *)

Timing[Nor @@ mySquareFreeQ @ data]
(* {0.078125, True} *)
```

So my implementation is about twice as fast as using the built-in `SquareFreeQ`.

**Explanation**

I cheated, of course. [`MoebiusMu`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MoebiusMu.html) is what `SquareFreeQ` uses internally (`MoebiusMu` returns zero if the argument has multiple prime factors). However, `MoebiusMu` is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) whereas `SquareFreeQ` is not. So it is somewhat faster to evaluate `MoebiusMu` with a list argument than it is to explicitly map `SquareFreeQ` over the list.